# Insert delimiters using rule lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have data without delimiters. There are 10 columns where the starting digit of each column and length of each column value is specified as below:

```
starting_digit = [1,5,7,9,12,14,15,16,17,19]
col_length = [4,2,2,3,2,1,1,1,2,8]
df.columns = ["year","st","stfips","county","registry","race","hispanic","sex","age","pop"]
```

May I know how to apply the "rules" (starting_digit and col_length ) to split the data into different columns?

```
data:
1969AL01001991910000000159
1969AL01001991910100000657
1969AL01001991910200001137
1969AL01001991910300000956
1969AL01001991910400000721
1969AL01001991910500000424
....
2019WY56035992921000000001
2019WY56035992921100000001
2019WY56035992921200000003
2019WY56035992921300000002
2019WY56035992921400000003
```

Comment: I get `col_length` but what does `starting_digit` do?

Comment: yes, either one is required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `pandas.read_fwf()`:

```
df = pd.read_fwf("data.txt", 
                  widths=[4,2,2,3,2,1,1,1,2,8], 
                  names=["year","st","stfips","county","registry","race","hispanic","sex","age","pop"])
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying with this now .. since data is big, it is taking more time to create df